# Creating new vertices with Ctrl + Click not working

Tags: vertices

I'm having this odd problem where blender isn't letting me hold Ctrl and left click to draw my points as I have done before. I deleted my cubes vertices in edit mode and I'm trying to draw from the view point of num7, I'm holding down my Ctrl, its a very simple thing to do but but the points aren't drawing. Any ideas what might wrong?

Comment: Is vertex select enabled?

Comment: in addition to what @stacker rightfully mentioned, if you had switched your Selection Preferences to Left Click Selection, you'll need to use Cltr + RMB to extrude vertices.

Comment: I'm sorry I'm an idiot, I was holding the left click and not the right because I thought I'd move the cursor >_< Thanks so much!

Answer (score 2):

I too had the same problem. I noticed that I had was using face select instead of vertex select. Changing that might help you. Good luck!

Comment: Ugh, this is like when a veteran IT worker wonders why the computer doesn't turn on only to find it's unplugged. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone coming here with blender 2.8+ and have right click on as it was used in earlier blender versions the new combination for me was ctrl + LEFT click.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + **Left-Click**

Answer (score 1):

In current versions of blender use <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd> + Right Mouse Button.  To create a new connected vertex in edit mode.

<kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd>+left click is no longer the shortcut in 2.83.1 or older versions.